# \qed or \qedhere at the end of split environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, amsmath, amsthm

While I was trying to improve my latest document with respect to its `\qed` symbols at the end of `amsthm`'s `proof` environment i came across an interesting point. Assume the proof ends with some formula, that is finally representing the form the lemma/theorem proposes.

Something like

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,amstext,amsfonts,bm,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
...
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        A&= B \\
         &= C\\
         &= D&\qedhere
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

While using `\qedhere` just in `equation` or `align` would put the symbol below any number (or at least to that side for `euqation*`), here the symbol is placed far to the left, even with using the additional column with `&`. Putting it after `\end{split}` would center it vertically with respect to the three columns, so my question is

How can I get the `\qed` symbol to the bottom right (text border) of an (equation-)split environment?

Where I would prefer a global solution for all `split`s where I mention `\qedhere` at the end.

Comment: Interesting one, I think it might be an idea to contact Barbara Beeton and tell her about this one.

Comment: @daleif I believe that barbara follows the ams* tags here, so she'll spot it soon.

Comment: @tohecz I'm sure your are right, I've also added the `asmthm` tag, just to be sure.

Comment: @Ronny: `amstext` and `amsfonts` are not needed in your package list, they are automatically loaded by `amsmath` and `amssymb`.

Comment: Yep. And `bm` is also not neccessary, i noticed already :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the best approach in this particular case is to use `align*`, as that behaves well with `\qedhere` since each line is treated separately.  (any of the multi-line options that treats lines separately should work equally well.)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
...
\begin{align*}
        A&= B \\
         &= C\\
         &= D \qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

this isn't always ideal -- `cases`, for example, will always force the tombstone to the center vertically -- but the request has been made often enough to place the tombstone on the last line, that it should be considered as a possible option.  i am adding it to the formal list of requests.

as noted elsewhere, with flush left equations and equation numbers on the right, there is a built-in conflict.  that is why ams document classes default to using equation numbers on the left.

Comment: Note that the OP _also_ wants an equation number, which of course you don't get with `align*`.

Comment: It was more on occasion, but yes, I want to refer to “the estimates from (1)”. My old approach was _quick and dirty_ to use an `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` after the `equation` but that's of course really only _quick and dirty_.

Comment: @HendrikVogt -- actually, you *can* get an equation number if you use `\tag{\theequation}` on (say) line 2; you have to `\stepcounter{equation}` before the `align*` though to get the correct value.

Comment: I'll accept your answer as the correct way to do that, _though_ semantically I mean something different, when i use `split` instead of `align` and it would be nice to have a way to `split` an equation and have it's `\quedhere` at the bottom right (and maybe also it's number, but okay).

Comment: @Ronny -- the request for a method of moving the box to the bottom line of a multi-line subequation has been added to the list of requests for `amsmath`/`amsthm`.  but it's unclear to me how an equation number on the right should best be presented along with the box.  can you describe what you'd like to see in that situation?  (no promises, but it's useful to have the information on the record.)

Comment: For the case of `fleqn` of course the placing is not that easy. I think it would be best to vertically center the number and put the `\qed`to the bottom right. If they overlap (which would not happen in my cases), the package should either place a warning or move the number higher (or the `\qed` lower or maybe both on an equal amount?). That's what I'm thinking. One could also try to determine, whether the height of the equation line is smaller than `3\baselineskip` (=> eq.nr and `\qed`meet), and issue a warning then or something like that.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I noticed an interesting behavior with `align*` which is how I wound up here: If you forget to place the & in the align environment and don't notice (because you actually ended up only using one line) and later come back and insert `\qedhere` to fix the placement of the box, the placement of the box will be on top of the last character in the line.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I'd do if I was using `ntheorem` instead of `amsthm`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,bm}
\usepackage[ntheorem]{empheq}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath\square}
\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
...
\begin{empheq}{equation}
\begin{split}
A&= B \\
&= C\\
&= D
\end{split}
\end{empheq}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image: latex output]

Comment: Well without `\qedhere` the `\square` would be placed (in amsthm) _after_ the end of the equation, which is at least `\baselineskip` (or something like that) below the placement `ntheorem` obtains here. And I might have text before the equation, so my proof is not just an equation which might be the reason for the placement here.

Comment: That it not the point here. The point is that `ntheorem` and `empheq` combined can place the square at the very bottom of the equation, try replacing `D` with something tall or deep, `amsthm` cannot do that AFAIR `\qedhere` will be placed in the same location as the equation number (if there is one), which may look strange.

Comment: Oh, i overred some code lines, I'm sorry. Well then, I'm neither using `empheq` nor `ntheorem` and while your demonstration shows nicely, what I would like to have, I would also like to have that using `amsmath`and `amsthm` :)

Comment: Of course, `[fleqn]` and the `\qed` that i would like to have, will overlap, if `split` only consists of 2 lines (none of them exceeding the text line height). Then the default is - of course - preferable.

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice question! I guess that `\qedhere` is not designed for the purpose you want to achieve. I can only offer a workaround, and it's only simple if you have an *odd* number of lines. (Since for two lines you won't want to use it anyway, the problem starts with four lines.) The idea: Use the `align` environment with `\nonumber` instead of `equation` and `split`.

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
...
\begin{align}
        A&= B \nonumber \\
         &= C \\
         &= D \nonumber \qedhere
\end{align}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, had the same idea a few minutes ago, but then noticed, the placement of the number gets even worse, if some of the lines, let's say the first two, are increased in height, due to an integral or stuff like that. So your idea works for an _odd_ number of lines, where all lines are equal in height (or at least equal in height with symmetry to the mid line).

Comment: @Ronny: The question that I can't really answer is where the number should best be put. I guess you want to have it vertically centered, correct? For two lines this is nice, but I'm never sure if it's really appropriate for more lines. Nevertheless, your actual question remains unanswered!

Comment: Well I like them vertically centered, that's right. Even for more than 2 lines I think, it clarifies the connection. But that's of course just an oppinion. Nevertheless, my actual question even remains unsolved for `equation*` using a `split`.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed an interesting further point. If you are for example using the style provided by Springer `svmult.cls`, then the `\qedhere` is not available (haven't checked why though).

Then another approach would be (at least for numberings being at the right side of the page) to use

```
\tag*{\qeq}
```

both in `split` of an `equation` environment or an `align`/`align*` environment.

Nevertheless, compared to my original question, this of course implies, that the last line of the environment is not equipped with a number (or better: not needed to be equipped...)

Comment: i haven't checked the springer class, but the `\qedhere` i'm familiar with depends on coordination between `amsthm` and `amsmath`.  for ams document classes, both of these packages are built in; i don't know of other document classes (or theorem packages) that provide this coordination.

Comment: Thanks for the info, in fact `svmult.cls` does not load any math packages and I happened to only load `amsmath` but not `amsthm`, because the latter caused definition conflicts with `svmult.cls`. So the coordination is missing.