# How to put an qedsymbol at the end of an array environment?

Tags: theorems, arrays

I want to put an qedsymbol at the end of a non-proof environment such as

```
\begin{theorem}
This is a funny equation
\[
\begin{array}{rcl}
x+y&=&z,\\
a+b&=&c.
\end{array}
\]
\end{theorem}
```

and I want to put the symbol at the right side of the line of

```
a+b=c
```

but not the right side of the whole list of equations.

And also in a proof environment I want to make qedsymbol at the right side of the line of a+b=c but not the right side of the whole list of equations.

```
\begin{proof}
So we have
\[
\begin{array}{rcl}
x_1+y^2&=&z^3,\\
a^2+b_2&=&c^6.
\end{array}
\]
\end{proof}
```

**QUESTION:** *Who has a good way to do these two things together?*

All the codes of mine are as follows.

```
\documentclass[11pt,b5paper]{ctexbook}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs}
%%%change qedsymbol%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\ensuremath\boxtimes}
%%%set theorems%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{定理}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{引理}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{推论}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{命题}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{定义}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{评注}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{示例}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{习题}
\newtheorem{thesis}[theorem]{论题}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{猜想}
\newtheorem{convention}[theorem]{约定}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{问题}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{公理}    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This is a funny equation
\[
\begin{array}{rcl}
x+y&=&z,\\
a+b&=&c.\qedhere
\end{array}
\]
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
So we have
\[
\begin{array}{rcl}
x_1+y^2&=&z^3,\\
a^2+b_2&=&c^6.\qedhere
\end{array}
\]
\end{proof}


\begin{proof}
So we have
\begin{align*}
x+y&=z,\\
a+b&=c.\qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

The compiled PDF sample is also as follows.

[image]

**NOTE**: the new command `\myqed` I defined can only work in the equation environment (with only 1 line of equations), but can't work in the `align*` environment. So I still haven't solve the problem.

Comment: Try looking at `\qedhere`, in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101929/qed-or-qedhere-at-the-end-of-split-environment) or [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130641/how-to-put-the-qed-symbol-of-a-proof-at-the-right-place-inside-align) for example.

Comment: Also, when you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: A working sample has been provided. `\qedhere` doesn't work

Comment: Replace the `array` witl `align` as in the example sin the linked posts. The way you are using `array` is giving you incorrect spacing.

Comment: It doesn't work either! @Peter Grill

Comment: Are you just trying to find the command for a qed _symbol_? `\square` or `\blacksquare` (depending on your style) will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,b5paper]{ctexbook}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs}
%%%change qedsymbol%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\ensuremath\boxtimes}
%%%set theorems%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{定理}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{引理}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{推论}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{命题}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{定义}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{评注}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{示例}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{习题}
\newtheorem{thesis}[theorem]{论题}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{猜想}
\newtheorem{convention}[theorem]{约定}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{问题}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{公理}    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This is a funny equation
\begin{align*}
x+y&=z,\\
a+b&=c.\qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
So we have
\begin{align*}
x_1+y^2&=z^3,\\
a^2+b_2&=c^6.\qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}


\begin{proof}
So we have
\begin{align*}
x+y&=z,\\
a+b&=c.\qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If array environment is the last object in the theorem or proof environment, then you should do this:

```
\begin{theorem}
This is a funny equation
\[
\begin{array}[b]{...}
....
\end{array}\qedhere
\]
\end{theorem}
```

Comment: @Kuttens -- Try this: `\[a+b+c=e.\qedhere\]`

Comment: I don't know how to apply to definitions.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{theorem}[1][]{\begin{thm}[#1]\pushQED{\qed}}{\popQED\end{thm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
This is a funny equation
\begin{align*}
x+y&=z,\\
a+b&=c.\qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
So we have
\begin{align*}
x+y&=z,\\
a+b&=c.\qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But I use `\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs}` and so your method doesn't work. I don't know why.

Comment: @Kuttens [amsthdoc](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf) page 2: "If the amsthm package is used with a non-AMS document class and with the
amsmath package, amsthm must be loaded after amsmath, not before."

Comment: In fact, I define a new theorem environment and a new proof environment in my actual file, and so these codes don't work

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong. Some tips: Don't use `array` environment in this case. `amsthm` must be loaded after `amsmath`, not before.

Comment: @Kuttens -- if you're defining new theorem and proof environments, then there's little point in using `amsthm` at all.  maybe there's a different package for theorems that would suit you better.

Comment: @barbara beeton -- In my opinion, the problem is not the `amsthm`. Probably Kuttens doesn't apply well the solution in his/her code.

Comment: @tomacs -- it may be true that the solution is not applied well, but the statement "I define a new theorem environment and a new proof environment" strongly implies that nothing is left of the `amsthm` definitions, so it makes no sense to use it.  since the redefinitions aren't shown, it's impossible to tell what's happening.  (caveat: i'm responsible for maintaining the `amsthm` documentation, so i'm biased.)

Comment: @barbara beeton -- Dear Barbara, of course you are right:) But I suppose that Kuttens defines the `theorem` environment with `amsthm`, as it is in his/her code. And the `proof` is not redefined in the code of question.

Comment: @tomacs -- fair enough.  you've used the "push/pop" code from the `amsthm` `proof` environment (or close enough; i haven't checked) to add the qed trap to a `theorem` definition; this is the right approach.  this is in the "pending" list, but when/if it's finally added, it will apply more generally.  kuttens' statement about redefining theorem and proof isn't in the question, but in a comment to your answer.  i think we don't know enough to give a definitive answer.

Comment: @barbara beaten , I post all my codes.

Comment: @tomacs , I post all my codes.

Comment: @Kuttens -- I fixed your code in a new answer. You didn't apply well the solution!